# Does map.set() overwrite the value if the key already exists?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was wondering if map.set() overwrites the value if the key already exists in the map.

How can I test this easily when in a big project?
Are there any website you can use for javascript coding?

Comment: [Yes](https://jsbin.com/wojaquridi/edit?js,console)

Comment: what should happen instead?

Comment: An exception ('key already present')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [developer.mozilla.org on Map.set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set)

> The set() method adds or updates an element with a specified key and a
> value to a Map object.

I recommend looking up prototype functions on native objects on [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) at first.

Comment: I didn't know you could go the the definition page of a certain definition.
I've looked at [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) but there it wasn't clear.